# Laravel - Model binding not working when I use accessors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mutators

I want to populate my select box from the Laravel IoC Container.

**App\Http\Utilities\BillingHelper.php**

[image: GitHub Logo]

**views/billing/create.blade.php**

[image: GitHub Logo]

**views/billing/edit.blade.php**

[image: GitHub Logo]

Create the table:

[image: GitHub Logo]

Now, instead of the value, i want to display some flags and currency symbols.

Should i use mutators?

[image: GitHub Logo]

**Problem**

If i use mutators, when i open the edit page, i see always the first value selected, from the BillingHelper, instead of the choosen one.

[image: GitHub Logo]

[image: GitHub Logo]

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it should be a comment, but I have no reputation.

What if, on you edit page, you replace null on Form::select with $client->language and $client->currency.

I know that you area binding the values with Form::Model. But worth a try.

Comment: Or, to improve it, add old('currency', $client->currency) instead of null.

Comment: Thanks, Mauro, but still not working if i use Accesor to change the code in flags and symbols. Any accesor alternative ? :D.. or a better way to use it.

Comment: It's not an Accessor alternative, but...

Your data will be static or you are going to change it doing a DB query? Because, you could just create another file on config folder, and retrieve that as config('file_name.currency')

If you want the name of the currency: config('file_name.currency.eur')

Comment: Thanks, Mauro, I tried also with view composers. I got the same error... - "Your data will be static or you are going to change it" I want to populate my select boxes from an array. I don't think i need to create an individual table for each select box I use. After submitting the form, I want to get the selected values from database, and display them on my index page, in my table. I also need to change some values with some symbols and icons(language flags etc..), on my index page (not in the database)

Comment: I've tried, so far, to do this with accessors, but the edit page(model binding) don't work anymore. I don't get the selected values anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### **When you use mutators the matching won't occur anymore. You'll have to use a matching static array according to the values you'll return. (the flags)**

You can make it work if you make a mutator for saving the data also and simplify again to the ['it', 'en', 'lv'], otherwise your saved data will differ and the initial mutator won't work the second time. You can still make a one-time-only test.

#### **This is why:**

Your form binding is using $bill->language to retrieve the actual stored data, and compare it with the values in your $bill::lang static array. If no match found, than the first value will be always selected.

Can you provide the the currency and language fields definition in the migration for the bill?

Also retrive your values from your bills DB and paste them here for language and currency. They must be in the defined static sets.

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel` has a way of skipping the accessor/mutator by using
`$model->getOriginal('data_field')`.
The "`getOriginal()`" gets the model's original attribute values.